# Is it possible to use CPropertyPage created in DLL in a main application?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a dialog-based MFC application that hosts `CPropertySheet`.

The idea is to scan some folder for DLLs, load each of them dynamically (using `LoadLibrary()`), acquire a pointer to a function that would work like a `CPropertyPage` factory, use that function to create per-DLL `CPropertyPage` instances and insert them to `CPropertySheet`.

In other words, scan a folder for plugins, acquire the per-plugin property pages and insert them to `CPropertySheet` of the main application so each plugin would have it's own options GUI.

Plugins are implemented in a form of regular MFC dlls (not extension dlls). I'm aware that `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())` is to be employed.

Each `CPropertyPage` being created must be derived from an abstract interface (say, `IPluginOptionsPropPage`) so it would be possible to cast the pointer that factory function returns to `IPluginOptionsPropPage`.

This task is supposed to be a routine one, however, I could not found any sound examples.

Comment: It would be better to create a sample application that tries to do that, and if you encounter any problems, then post questions about them. Right now the question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done.   You can try these steps

1. Load the property page library using ::LoadLibrary.  The return handle is the handle for the resource.

   ```
   m_hResInstance = ::LoadLibrary(strFile);
   ```
2. Before creating the instance of the property page, set the instance of the resource handle to the library's handle.

   ```
   m_hCurrent = AfxGetResourceHandle();

   AfxSetResourceHandle(hResInstance);

   //Create your property sheet here.
   ```
3. Then reset the resource handle to the current process resource.

   ```
   //Reset the previous

   AfxSetResourceHandle(m_hCurrent);
   ```

This will enable you to load the resource of the property page,  others like header and library or function pointer can be used as intended.